# Tomcat Servlet Default Datetime Format

Tags: tomcat, servlets, formatting, java, datetime-format

I'm trying out Endeavour Software Project Management.It's running as a servlet in Tomcat (Catalina). The package came with tomcat and jre configure, got it running quite easily. Everything was fine, except that the Datetime format wasn't as per my machine's configuration. I couldn't find a place to configure the Datetime format. Not in the servlet itself, or any of the configuration file I've dug through. Btw, I'm using a Windows 7 x86 machine. Any idea to change the format without touching the source code?

Comment: You meant to say that the datetime format which Endeavour Software Project Management is using doesn't adhere the server machine's default locale as obtained by `Locale#getDefault()` or the client's default locale as obtained by `HttpServletRequest#getLocale()`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with jre's programming. The default locale is configured in windows' Region and Language Settings. Does tomcat require a different way to configure it's locale? If so, where should I do it?

Comment: *Which* locale is it then "incorrectly" using? The one of the server machine or the one of the client machine? That may namely more be a configuration issue of the webapp software in question, not of Tomcat/JRE. Play with client (webbrowser) locale settings to check it ... Firefox example: *Tools > Options > Content > Languages*.

Comment: Ah, now I get you. I'm running both on the same machine. I just checked from another machine, it's also wrong. I did change the language in my firefox, it's still not right. I'm using dd/MM/yyyy, but it's displaying MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: In other words, the Endeavour Software Project Management webapp is *not* respecting the client's locale? Well, that would be a configuration setting of the webapp software in question. Since I've never heard of it, I can't post an answer for that. But you now at least know where to look. Check its documentation or contact its support and so on. Good luck :)

Comment: Is there a way to set it default in tomcat or jre?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can at highest change the platform default locale of the server machine. It's unclear what platform the server is using, but if it's Windows, you can do it in the control panel: http://java.com/en/download/help/locale.xml

But you're still dependent on the webapp software whether it picks/uses the correct locale. Maybe it has the locale hardcoded or it should be externally configureable. Refer the webapp's documentation.

Changing the server's platform default locale will however affect all visitors since the webapp doesn't seem to respect the client's default locale (as per the comments on your question).

Comment: This seems closer. I'm setting my locale to US English, while I'm using dd/MM/yyyy for my date format settings. Maybe it's taking the default for en-us. I'll try with en-UK and see if it changes. Btw, the java control panel is showing MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: `dd/MM/yyyy` is IIRC typical for Canada and France. Give it a try.